# How to make the player move according to the camera motion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now I'm a beginner game developer and I'm working on a game so I have set the camera motion that when you move the mouse the player rotates however I want to make the WASD keys work to the direction the player is rotated. Basically when I rotate the camera to the left the W key still moves the player on the Z dimension. How can I fix this?
Here's my player rotation code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
 public float speedH = 2.0f;
 public float speedV = 2.0f;
 private float yaw = 0.0f;
 private float pitch = 0.0f;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start()
 {

 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {

    yaw += speedH * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    pitch -= speedV * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch, yaw, 0.0f);

 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO @The golden hacker. Please provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so the SO users can help you.

Comment: Note that [`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html): `When you read the .eulerAngles property, Unity converts the Quaternion's internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles. Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned. This can cause confusion if you are trying to gradually increment the values to produce animation.`

Comment: Inmyour code I don't see anything for movement at all ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving in the direction the character is facing is a simple work for **Transform.forward** and **Transform.right** because you need to move the player based on local position and rotation and not the world one.

For example, you could have

```
void Move (float h, float v)
 {
     movement.Set (h, 0f, v);
     movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

     playerRigidbody.MovePosition (transform.position + (transform.forward * movement.z) + (transform.right * movement.x));

 }
```

The **Rigidbody** is what you need to move it, if you want an object that is always moving in the direction is facing you could easily do a

```
transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed;
```

In this case, to go back you should subtract instead of add.
But use my first suggestion for your player :D

**EDIT**

In your update you can add

```
Move(yaw, pitch);
```

Comment: I tried your first  code in my player movement script but it gave me the following error:Assets\Movement.cs(12,9): error CS0103: The name 'movement' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: sorry you need to declare it before, it is a Vector3 @Thegoldenhacker

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm 100% understanding, I've added my player rotation code to the post check that out and tell me where to add your script

Comment: movement it's just a Vector3. You need to write Vector3 movement; On the top of the program, if you have other problems you can also read there : https://answers.unity.com/questions/1250146/move-a-player-in-the-direction-he-is-facing.html

Comment: Hmm well I see now what you meant but now I need to declare speed as unity is giving me the same error from before but now the name "speed" does not exist in the current context, so what do I declare speed? Sorry if I'm wasting your time.

Comment: speed is just a value for the speed of movement, it could be just a public float so you can set it in the inspector

Comment: So I have successfully added your code to my script without getting any errors but it didn't solve my problem I still can't use the WASD keys with the rotation of the player :(. But from the link you sent me I think I have to move my script in the update function to the function that you sent me right? If I'm right then can you send me another answer and write how my code should look now?

Comment: added @Thegoldenhacker

Comment: I tried the code and there is a good news and a bad news, the good news is that the code worked and the bad news is that it didn't give me the result I expected I don't think you understand what I wanted to do. What basically happened is that when I rotate the player to the left or right it starts to move left and right. What I wanted is that when I rotate the player the W key is supposed to make me move forward to the direction I'm facing but the W key still goes in one direction no matter the rotation.

Comment: sorry add this: Move(Input.GetKeyDown(keycode.w), Input.GetKeyDown(keycode.s));  @Thegoldenhacker

Comment: It gave me the following error:Assets\CameraMovement.cs(36,14): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'float'